# Pass msbuild properties to devenv.exe on the command line

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, msbuild, continuous-integration

I am building a solution automatically with `devenv.exe` on our CI server, this works totally fine. For deployment purposes I added a nuget package (namely OctoPack). Its documentation tells me to pass properties to MSBuild when building, but as I am using devenv, that is not possible.

Through research, I learned that I can add a **PropertyGroup** to the the `.csproj` of the project, to add these properties. I would prefer not to do that, as I need to replace certain values (like the version number) in those properties, so I do not want to put placeholders into those strings. Additionally, I would need to be able to have those PropertyGroups only active when building on the CI server, not when developing and building locally.

This ultimately leads to my question: Can I somehow pass those properties, which are usually passed to MSBuild (via `/p:`), to devenv on the command line?

Comment: There is no documented way of doing this, likely because there's a better alternative: call msbuild directly to build your solution - your CI server should be able to that - and pass properties as you wish. Other alternative, if you must use devenv, is to set those properties as environment variables but I'd really advise against it.

Comment: devenv wraps MsBuild and add lots of VS specific properties, I am not qure sure why you use devenv.exe instead of Msbuild.exe

Comment: According to a bunch of posts on stackoverflow, devenv is the way to go as it is faster, restores packages automatically and so on @ColeWu

Comment: Not sure where you got that but imo it is misleading information. It would be strange if firing up an IDE which then uses msbuild would be faster than using msbuild directly. Also I've been using msbuild with automatic package restore for years, there should not be any problem with that, see e.g. http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/package-restore#Automatic_Package_Restore_in_Visual_Studio

Comment: Don't use devenv.exe.  Use Msbuild.exe.  Its not 2003 anymore.

Comment: use nuget.exe restore MySolution.sln to restore packages.  Then call msbuild.exe mySolution.sln

Comment: "According to a bunch of posts on stackoverflow, devenv is the way to go as it is faster,"  Post those links.  So we can go refute them.

Comment: By the way, because a visual studio install installs so much hidden voodoo, I forbid VS to be installed on the CI/Build machine.  It forces you to figure out dependencies earlier than later.

Comment: Did it with MSBuild now, thank you for the suggestions :)

Comment: Even though it's not 2003 anymore, MSBuild still can't build SSIS projects whereas devenv can. So there are cases where you really need devenv and you just can't use MSBuild, which is why I am disappointed by the accepted pseudo-answer to this post.

Comment: I decided to tackle the real problem which is to close the functionality gap between devenv and MSBuild in regarding to building projects so that the two tools can be used interchangeably (today MSBuild provides a subset of the build capabilities of devenv so they can't be used interchangeably). If you support this idea, please upvote this feature request: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/523612/support-ssis-ssrs-ssas-in-msbuild.html .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm posting an answer so that this question can be closed out).

1. I'd suggest not using devenv.exe on your CI server.
2. Start using msbuild.exe.
3. Pass in parameters using the

> /property:name=value  /p:name=value

4. use nuget.exe restore MySolution.sln to restore packages.

Comment: This answer should not be accepted. MSBuild functionality does not match 1 to 1 with devenv functionality; they overlap, yes, but devenv can, for example, build SSIS and SSRS projects whereas MSBuild cannot. The answer provided here is a workaround for most cases, which is nice to have, but it is not a real solution to the problem at hand (passing MSBuild properties to devenv, as the title of the question states).

Comment: One should use msbuild until there is a concrete reason why you shouldn't use msbuild.  (IMHO).  Yes, I have found a few cases where i had to use devenv.exe. (there is probably a SOF answer floating around somewhere).  As Marv suggests, feel free to add a new answer that documents your concerns.

Comment: Actually, I'm taking a different approach. From my perspective, we SHOULD be able to build every kind of  project with MSBuild and should never have to rely on a full IDE to build projects. I think that is the central problem here. That's why I opened this feature request for the VS team: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/523612/support-ssis-ssrs-ssas-in-msbuild.html . Please log in and vote if you think MSBuild should support SSxS projects. As for the answer, I will edit this one adding that it is not strictly possible to achieve what the title of the question states.

Comment: Yes, msbuild should be able to do everything devenv does. (and I will go vote) At the same time, the person who posted the question is satisfied with this answer........and he/she does not mention SSIS and SSRS, therefore I am rejecting the edit you proposed.  You've made your point "SSIS and SSRS are different when it comes to msbuild".  But this answer should not be thrown out because of a few fringe cases.

Comment: That's fine. I came here because I am forced to use devenv because of my project type. I thought by editing the answer I would help others like me in the future (the goal was not to throw out the answer). I hope the comments will be enough to help them out.

Comment: I upvoted.  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/523612/support-ssis-ssrs-ssas-in-msbuild.html  and yes.......they definately should support these in msbuild.

Comment: MSBuild functionality does not match 1 to 1 with devenv functionality, because 

devenv.exe mysolution.sln /build "Debug|x64"
works,
MS say to use -target: target as an option, but
msbuild mysolution.sln -target:Debug|x64:build
fails, with an error that the project does not contain the target Debug|x64. 
So MSBuild seems to be a bad replacement or the docuemnation is hard to understand or incomplete.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-en/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2022) `devenv.exe` does not provide any command-line switch for setting msbuild properties.

As stated in the other answer and comments, for modern projects, it would be better to use `msbuild.exe` instead of directly calling `devenv.exe`.

But if you need to use `devenv.exe` for building project-types which are not supported by msbuild (e.g. *.vdproj = Windows installer projects) you can set any msbuild-property right before calling devenv.exe by setting an environment variable:

> /property:name=value or /p:name=value

results in

> set name=value

In a subsequent call, then execute devenv.exe.

Comment: MSBuild functionality does not match 1 to 1 with devenv functionality, because 

devenv.exe mysolution.sln /build "Debug|x64"

works,
MS say to use -target: target as an option, but

msbuild mysolution.sln -target:Debug|x64:build

fails, with an error that the project does not contain the target Debug|x64. 
So MSBuild seems to be a bad replacement or the documenation is hard to understand or incomplete.


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-en/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022